# How to get an old boarding pass or some certificate?

Tags: tickets, airlines, refunds, delta-air-lines

My company is asking me to provide the boarding pass for reimbursement purposes. However I used the boarding pass via an app and did not print it out. I've found websites mentioning that it is not possible to recover an old boarding pass.

Can the airline company give me a certificate that I took the flight? Is there any other way to prove to my company that I took the flight?

---

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION AFTER COMMENTS:

My company is a University. They say that one could buy a ticket and later ask for the refund with the airline, and go to the place in a different way, so the purchase receipt does not prove it. The boarding pass should be acceptable, because you take it just after check-in. They told me without the boarding pass (Delta airlines already told me they can't provide), a document from Delta, mentioning that I boarded should be enough. Do you think Delta can provide this?

---

EDIT 2:

In the end, Delta provided me with a certificate.

Comment: Does your company not trust receipts you have from booking/paying for the ticket?  Also do you have any other evidence that you were at your destination? EG Hotel bills, car rental bills etc?

Comment: What airline have you taken? Many airlines will have that service

Comment: @NicolasFormichella: are you sure? Most will allow you to print a receipt of the purchase but not actually a boarding pass.

Comment: The company is Delta. They say I can't print a copy of boarding pass, just the purchase receipt, which the company says does not prove I took the flight (and did not get the refund for the ticket, for instance)

Comment: Are you a member of a frequent flyer scheme? Show them the record of your flights.

Comment: @Hilmar Yes, I am sure, looking for travel certificate on Google yields Emirates/Vistara...

Comment: Have you tried printing the ticket again? the status of the sector should be changed to "F" or "Flown", of course this is not a standard practice but many airlines do that. Also, when was the flight? how many months ago? there's a retention period the airlines must keep records, then they usually destroy it, to comply with authorities and GDPR etc..

Comment: What kind of company needs a boarding pass for expenses? What if you had missed your flight? They wouldn’t reimburse you?

Comment: Could you ask around your company how is it the exact procedure? I expect you are not the only one which fly (and with an app). And as usual company written rules are often obsolete, so companies has workaround (e.g. in past EU conferences has the obligatory group photo to show you participate, or attendance certificate). (or better: not companies but universities and government agencies had very obsolete rules, maybe you should fax them?)

Comment: A lot of companies these days will accept a screen shot or similar electronic document, rather than requiring paper. I would also expect them to know whether you attended the place you are supposed to have traveled to, so it's not as if you could cancel the ticket and stay home. But you should speak to your company's expenses department.

Comment: My various airline/hotel/rental car apps list past trips going back several years. It only lists actual usage, not any cancelled trips Does the app you used do that?

Comment: My company is a University. They say that one could buy a ticket and latter ask for the refund with the airline, and go to the place in a different way, so the purchase receipt does not prove it. The boarding pass should be acceptable, because you take it just after the check-in. They told me without the boarding pass (Delta airlines already told me they can't provide), a Document from Delta, mentioning that I boarded should be enough. Do you think Delta can provide this?

Comment: @Oalvinegro And you could also buy a fully refundable ticket, check in online, get the boarding pass, and then cancel the ticket and still get a refund.  Your university's "logic" is non-sensical.  But you already know that.

Comment: Yes. I know and argued that...They said they are minimizing the risks, fully refundable ticket would be too expensive, above their limits and so....Anyway...